# primefaces dataTable:how to hide column

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I want to hide some columns in a dataTable(e.g id,serial),the columns will be rendered because javascript  need access the value of the columns.
Any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `display: none` or `visibility: hidden`. You can find the difference in here: [What is the difference between visibility:hidden and display:none?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone)

Whatever you use, you will have access with javascript to those elements.

Also you can find [here](http://searchengineland.com/is-hiding-content-with-display-none-legitimate-seo-13643) a interesting point of view regarding the `usage of display:none`.

Comment: If primefaces could't do this,the only way may use javascript.Thanks.

Comment: @machcm.sz This is not Javascript, it's only CSS and the Primefaces components provide `style/styleClass` attribute for situations like this...

Comment: O,yeayea. I found  "display:none;" only hide the div under the td,but td not be affected. The result is 1px line left

Comment: @spauny: This doesn't answer the question in any way. It just builds exactly on top of my answer. It even starts with "There is no display: hidden." That `hidden` was a type on part. Please, just don't do a drive-by downvote, leave a comment explaining the reason like this.

Answer (score 3):

Just set the "rendered" attribute to "false":

```
<p:column rendered="false">
...
</p:column>
```

Comment: That does not hide it, using rendered="false" will prevent the column from being part of the HTML page.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try this:

```
<p:column style="display: none" //...
```

Comment: I didn't downvoted your answer even you deserved! How can you say that I don't answer to the question when it's the accepted one. Be careful next time, big guy, and clear that downvote, if you have decency!

Comment: @spauny: I did think you downvoted my answer. Sorry for that I apologize. But that's not the reason I downvoted your answer, you already know why I downvoted from the comment I posted on your answer.

Comment: @spauny: Oh yes and I will be more than happy to take it off if you edit you answer to make it look more like an answer to the OP.

Comment: @spauny: You could still improve it by mentioning where exactly he supposed to use that `display: none`. So that if in the future some one searching for the same problem ends up here, your answer would be sufficient enough to rectify his problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Prime NG, for angular, in p-column you can add attribute [hidden]="true". That solved my issue. Also, that column will show up in export CSV function which is kind of cool.

Comment: PrimeNG != PrimeFaces.  Please remove this answer